# default value for $_POST[];

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a problem with default value for $_POST[];
So i have a html form with textboxes and the informations is sent to a php script. The php script has a sql query that is being sent to my database. But if my textbox in html form is empty the query doesnt have a value. So i want to set my post to a default value 0 so it returns a value atleast.

So here is an example of html form (This is not my actuall script. Just an example.

```
<form action="testscript.php" method="POST">
    <input type="id" name="ID"/>
    <input type="text" name="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Ok so this script will send both id and test textboxes will always have a number value. And it sends the information to testscript.php

Here is testscript.php example

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'dbuser', 'dbpass', 'dbname');
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (id, test) VALUES ($id, $test)";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failed" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

Alright so now if i submit my html form to php script without inserting any text to the textboxes the query will look like this

```
INSERT INTO test_table (id, test) VALUES ( , )
```

But the query should be like this

```
INSERT INTO test_table (id, test) VALUES (0, 0)
```

So. I know i can use value attribute in the html tag but then the value will be visible in the textbox and i dont want that.

And i know i can do an if statment to make a default value like this

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $test = $_POST['test'];
} else {
    $test = 0;
}
```

But now the problem is that i would have to do that if statment for every textbox and my html form have more than 100 textboxes. So i dont want to make an if statment for every textbox because then my script will be way to big and it will take hours.

So is there any way to set a default value for all the textboxes without using if statment in php or value attribute in html form?

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and yes, if you want to do safe databasing, you'll go read that link, and you'll also find a solution to the "I don't wanna check 100 fields myself" problem.

Comment: You can shorten that expression with a ternary, and indeed that's how most of us do it because you need to check `isset($_POST['test'])` anyway to avoid undefined index notices.  `$test = isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : 0;`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even empty inputs will return true on `isset($_POST['test'])`, you may want to check for `!empty($_POST['test'])`

Comment: You can always set defaults in your database table itself as well.

Comment: Also, if your defaults are always 0, then you can perform a loop on the $_POST[] array.

Comment: Yeah. I loop would be a great option for me i think. But is there any way to loop all $_POST[] or do i need to write down every $_POST[] that i have?

Comment: that depends on the form fields. unchecked checkboxes are NOT submitted, and therefore won't be in $_POST at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know it seems like a pain but you MUST check that all inputs are valid. You can  simplify the amount of code by using a ternary operator like this.

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0;
$test = isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : 0;

....
```

And no, it won't take hours even with hundreds of them.

To make this slightly less painful to code you can use the power of looping with PHP's [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

The most painful part will be creating an array with all your field names

```
$fields = array('id', 'test', 'extra', 'more', ..., 'one_hundred');
```

Then loop through that array creating variable names and at the same time escaping the strings - if they are there - otherwise set a value of 0 (zero). You might want/need to set this to "" (empty string)

```
foreach($fields as $field_name)
{
   ${$field_name} = isset($_POST[$field_name]) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST[$field_name]) : 0;
}
```

You now have the variables $id, $test, $extra, $more, ...., $one_hundred available for your use.

Comment: Okey but im also using mysqli_real_escape_string for my text inputs. So how do i use it with that? $text = mysqli_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : 0); Like that?

Comment: @user3055512, check out my expanded answer

Comment: Okey. Finally im done setting up all the names and i have tested this and it works. Thank you sir !

Answer (score 0):

If your checkboxes have unique names, then you'll need to check them on the server side to see if they actually have values in them one by one by using the ternary

`isset($_POST["test"]) ? $_POST["test"] : 0`

However, if your checkboxes are in array form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="2 >
```

Then you could do the following:

```
foreach($_POST['courses'] as $course) {
    echo $course; // etc etc etc 
}
```

You can also set database defaults.

Another note, your code is prone to SQL injection. Although the question you have might simply be an example, you might just keep in mind there are better and safer ways of querying a database see [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) connections.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I do know about PDO but im a beginner in php so i want to learn the standard php code first before trying PDO. And my form has text inputs not checkboxes. Can i do the same for text inputs?

Comment: @user3055512 yes you may; it's the same idea.

Comment: @user3055512 Welcome! If it works, just accept answer when you get a chance. Cheers!

Comment: I have not tested this yet, But one thing i didnt really understand is what to do with the names since all the textboxes have different names. You showed how to do it with checkboxes but checkboxes uses the same name

Comment: @user3055512 if your textboxes all have different names, then you can't do the foreach loop I showed you. The point of having the same name of textboxes with the square bracket [] is so that it can be recognized as an array by PHP. If not, each textbox name must be manually checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use null check and define your default value like this :

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ?? 'John';
```

in my case the default value is John if the name is not defined. It gives the same result like this :

```
 $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : 'John';
```